# Getting error from trying to unpickle from file

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error from the code below when these (my) assumptions  are being met.

The assumptions are:

- 'rb' = "read bytes" = file is being read as bytes
- loads = load as bytes = file is being loaded as bytes (actually this one might be wrong)

First I'm trying to write pickled data to a file:

```
import pickle

variables = {        
    1:['enable_family_chng', '0'],
    2:['enable_genus_chng', '0'],
    3:['enable_species_chng', '0'],
    4:['new_family_name', '0'], 
    5:['new_genus_name', '0'],
    6:['new_species_name', '0'],
}

#if species change is true then also enable add map or just open folder
# define dictionary varaibles
# just set all the variables[n][1] to 1
# better way to write this?... I think so! jst nt yt


variables[1]=['enable_family',{enable_family_chng}]
variables[2]=['enable_genus_chng',{enable_genus_chng}]
variables[3]=['enable_species_chng',{enable_species_chng}]
variables[4]=['new_family_name',{new_family_name}]
variables[5]=['new_genus_name',{new_genus_name}]
variables[6]=['new_species_name',{new_species_name}]

with open("variables.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dumps(variables)
```

And then I try to read it from the file. The 1 thing I've tried

```
import pickle

with open("variables.pickle", "rb") as file:
    pickle.loads('variables.pickle' 'rb')
```

returns error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The 2 thing I have tried

```
import pickle

with open("variables.pickle", "r") as file:
    pickle.load('variables.pickle' 'r')
```

returns error

> TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes

Comment: You aren't loading correctly: (1) Use `pickle.load()`. (2) Actually load the file `variables = pickle.load(file)` and _not_ the _string_ `'variables.pickle'`.

Comment: You are also not dumping to the file. Use `pickle.dump(variables, file)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pickle into a *file* and then unpickle it, you need to use `.dump()`/`.load()`, and not `.dumps()`/`loads()`, which is dumping to/reading from a *string* (therefore the `s` at the end). Try:

```
import pickle

variables = {        
    1:['enable_family_chng', '0'],
    2:['enable_genus_chng', '0'],
    3:['enable_species_chng', '0'],
    4:['new_family_name', '0'], 
    5:['new_genus_name', '0'],
    6:['new_species_name', '0'],
}

with open("variables.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(variables, file)

with open("variables.pickle", "rb") as file:
    read_variables = pickle.load(file)

print(variables == read_variables)
```